# Remover div que contem uma classe especifica em html com o php

Tags: php

Exemplo:

```
$string = '<div class="teste"> Hello word </div> Hello pessoal';
```

Pretendo remover o div que contem a classe teste e os respetivo conteúdo.

Comment: Leia sobre as classes `DOMDocument` e `XPath`.

Answer (score -1):

Esta biblioteca PHP permite modificar o conteúdo HTML:

**[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**